# Most Pythonic way to convert None to an empty list in case a default argument is not passed in a Function?

Tags: python, list, function, nonetype, default-arguments

I want to write a general function that takes two input variables `var1`, `var2` and returns the concatenation of both.

Each variable has the default value `None`, and can be either a single element or a `list`.

The expected output should be a **list** (even if both `var1` and `var2` are `None`, it should return an empty list `[]`).

Below is my function:

```
def my_func(var1=None, var2=None):
    if not isinstance(var1, list):
        var1 = [var1]
    if not isinstance(var2, list):
        var2 = [var2]
    return var1 + var2
```

When I only input one variable, I get the following:

```
>>> lst = my_func(var2=[1, 2, 3])
>>> print(lst)
[None, 1, 2, 3]
```

**I want to get**

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Is there any way to convert `None` to `[]` in the function, **without changing the default `None` values**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check first if `var` (1 and 2) are `Not None`

```
def my_func(var1=None, var2=None):
    var1 = var1 if var1 is not None else []
    var2 = var2 if var2 is not None else []
    if not isinstance(var1, list):
        var1 = [var1]
    if not isinstance(var2, list):
        var2 = [var2]

    return var1 + var2
```

This will cover many cases, such as :

```
print(my_func(var2=[1, 2, 3]))
print(my_func(var1=None,var2=[1, 2, 3]))
print(my_func(var1=0,var2=[1, 2, 3]))
print(my_func(var1=False,var2=[1, 2, 3]))
print(my_func(var1='',var2=[1, 2, 3]))
```

---

```
[1, 2, 3]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[1, 2, 3]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[0, 1, 2, 3]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[False, 1, 2, 3]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
['', 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `None` you could use `[]` as a default argument for each `var`.

```
def my_func(var1 = [], var2 = []):
    if not isinstance(var1, list):
        var1 = [var1]
    if not isinstance(var2, list):
        var2 = [var2]
    return var1 + var2 
        
lst = my_func(var2=[1, 2, 3])
print(lst)
```

However as user `mkrieger1` suggested in the comments it might be a bad idea as seen in this question ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) so instead you can do this:

```
def my_func(var1 = None, var2 = None):
    var1 = [] if var1 is None else var1
    var2 = [] if var2 is None else var2

    if not isinstance(var1, list):
        var1 = [var1]
    if not isinstance(var2, list):
        var2 = [var2]
    return var1 + var2 

    
lst = my_func(var2=[1, 2, 3])
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @solif.py answer in case you **want** to keep the None value (hence the default value is **not** a mutable object) then run a simple test as so:

```
def my_func(var1=None, var2=None):
    if not var1:
        var1 = []
    if not var2:
        var2 = []
    if not isinstance(var1, list):
        var1 = [var1]
    if not isinstance(var2, list):
        var2 = [var2]

    return var1 + var2


lst = my_func(var2=[1, 2, 3])
print(lst)
```

- Regarding function's parameters when are Mutable or not mutable check [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

> EDIT:

After further review your code, you can actually just change the `if not isinstance(var1, list)` line as so:

```
def my_func(var1=None, var2=None):

    if not isinstance(var1, list):
        var1 = []
    if not isinstance(var2, list):
        var2 = []
    

    return var1 + var2


lst = my_func(var2=[1, 2, 3])
print(lst)
```

### Other solution

**NOTE @Cid answer basically changes the argument var1 or var2 only if is equal to None hence the following can be done:**

```
def my_func(var1=None, var2=None):

    if var1 == None:
        var1 = []
    if var2 == None:
        var2 = []
    if not isinstance(var1, list):
        var1 = [var1]
    if not isinstance(var2, list):
        var2 = [var2]
    return var1 + var2


lst = my_func(var1=False, var2=[1, 2, 3])
print(my_func(var2=[1, 2, 3]))
print(my_func(var1=None,var2=[1, 2, 3]))
print(my_func(var1=0,var2=[1, 2, 3]))
print(my_func(var1=False,var2=[1, 2, 3]))
print(my_func(var1='',var2=[1, 2, 3]))
```

**output**

```
[1, 2, 3]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[1, 2, 3]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[0, 1, 2, 3]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[False, 1, 2, 3]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
['', 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score -2):

This is how I would remove all None from a list:

```python
def my_func(var1=None, var2=None):
    lst = []
    c = 0
    
    if not isinstance(var1, list):
        var1 = [var1]
    if not isinstance(var2, list):
        var2 = [var2]
    lst =  var1 + var2

    for i in lst:
        if i == None:
            lst.pop(c)
        c += 1

    return lst
    

lst_ = my_func(var2=[1, 2, 3])
print(lst_)
```

I use a for loop to iterate each item in a list. If the item == None, the code removes it.

Comment: I don't think is this...

Comment: I mean it does work and give the desired output, doesn't it?

Comment: it does, but is not what is asking, check the other answer and you should understand what he asking about